# Need to combine the following string objects under a preceding number

Tags: ruby

```
a=[1,'hi','what',2,'how','where',3,'one',4,'two','three','four',5,'five','six']
```

or

```
a = ["1",'hi','what',"2",'how','where',"3",'one',"4",'two','thre‌​e','four',"5",'five'‌​,'six']
```

I need to create the array of hash like

```
a=[{1=>['hi','what']},{2=>['how','where']},{3=>['one']},{4=>['two','three','four']},{5=>['five','six']}]
```

Can I use any predefined function to achieve this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages along with "[mcve]". You've given us input data and an expected output, basically requirements, but you haven't shown any effort toward solving the problem, which is essential. What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
a = [1,'hi','what',2,'how','where',3,'one',4,'two','three','four',5,'five','six']

p a.slice_before(Integer).map{ |int, *words| { int => words } }
#=> [{1=>["hi", "what"]}, {2=>["how", "where"]}, {3=>["one"]}, {4=>["two", "three", "four"]}, {5=>["five", "six"]}]
```

Note that an array of hashes with distinct keys could be condensed in one single hash :

```
a.slice_before(Integer).map{ |int, *words| [int, words] }.to_h
#=> {1=>["hi", "what"], 2=>["how", "where"], 3=>["one"], 4=>["two", "three", "four"], 5=>["five", "six"]}
```

Update :

If your keys are strings that look like a digit, you could try :

```
a = ["1",'hi','what',"2",'how','where',"3",'one',"4",'two','three','four',"5",'five','six']
a.slice_before(/^\-?\d+$/).map{ |int, *words| [int.to_i, words] }.to_h
#=> {1=>["hi", "what"], 2=>["how", "where"], 3=>["one"], 4=>["two", "three", "four"], 5=>["five", "six"]}
```

Comment: I was about to post something almost identical :)

Comment: Hi, it absolutely answers my question, but I want the answer for another possibility as well for an example, If array being `a = ["1",'hi','what',"2",'how','where',"3",'one',"4",'two','three','four',"5",'five','six']` Is there any way to group under the numbers?

Comment: You can pass a pattern to `slice_before`, i.e. `slice_before(/^-?\d+$/)`

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks. As a bonus, it also works with `slice_before(Integer)`